# Axes categoric rather than my numeric (data points) - 3D surface plotly in r

Tags: r, 3d, plotly, axes

I am trying to plot a 3D surface, using plot_ly on r. I have (x,y,z) coordinates for each point. I have put the x values in a vector, the y values in a vector, and the z values in a matrix (of size x by y).

I've used the function:

```
plot_ly(x = distance, y = width, z = elevation) %>% add_surface()
```

And it gives me

[image: this plot]

The z axis is fine however the x and y axes are categoric rather than what my data points are eg. (241, 89, 242.579). How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
plot_ly(x = as.numeric(distance), y = as.numeric(width), z = elevation) %>% add_surface()
```